# who watches the watchmen

Tags: debate, moderação

I was trying to contribute to stackoverflow at my local country (Brazil), and yesterday some of the local moderation team pursued me. They removed some of my reputation and they voted against my posts.

I believe that this happened because their egocentric personalities. The moderation team want all the glitz relating to certain types of subjects to their own answers.

In my opinion it affects the credibility of the forum and shrinks the community. I'm considering not contribute anymore to the local community.

How can I report that situation?

Comment: Looking at your [reputation tab](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/11676/gustavo-emmel?tab=reputation) I see some votes were reversed, and answers were unaccepted. Sounds like a moderator acted to reverse fraudulent votes here instead. If you disagree with that action, you need to use the [contact form](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact).

Comment: Gustavo, eu posso te garantir que nenhum moderador votou contra os seus posts, nem agiu em causa própria. O que ocorreu foi o que o Martijn Pieters disse. Tem certeza que quer tratar disso em público? Se preferir, temos outros canais para discutir o assunto de forma privada.

Comment: Veja isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

Comment: Da próxima vez que tiver qualquer tipo de problema no site tente entender o que aconteceu ao invés de desmerecer e desrespeitar as pessoas que cuidam do nosso site para mantê-lo limpo e organizado. Existem atividades irregulares na sua reputação, e independente se foi ou não de má fé esses pontos devem ser revertidos. Veja o link que o Andrey postou acima.

Comment: Respondendo a pergunta: *The community does.* E além disso, prestamos atenção nos usuários normais também. O procedimento é **igualzinho** no SO e no SOPT.

Comment: Já agora a frase de cima não está bem traduzida "... de recursos de professional and enthusiast programmers" ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. Verdade, mas o texto em inglês faz parte da descrição do SO e não tem como ser traduzido.

Comment: Engraçado que dizem que não votaram contra, mas no mesmo instante que me tomaram reputação por motivos pelo qual não sei / concordo ainda negativaram meus posts. Pensava que esse era um forum sério...

Comment: Gustavo, não tem votos contra. Você já recebeu mensagens privadas explicando em mais detalhes o que houve. Se olhar seu [histórico de reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/11676/gustavo-emmel?tab=reputation), verá a reversão de votos a favor, 2 votos de aceitação de respostas que também fizeram parte da reversão, e uma retirada de voto a favor avulsa, que penso ter sido feita por outro usuário (eu não tenho acesso detalhado a quem vota em quem, só o staff da Stack Exchange tem). Os votos contra nesta pergunta aqui no meta [expressam discordância](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1668)

Comment: @GustavoEmmel como disse o bfavaretto acima ^^^ e podes ver [nesta imagem](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1411372924.png) não tiveste **NENHUM** voto negativo, só reversões e aceitações desfeitas.

Answer (score 14):

Olá, Gustavo.

Não sei se ficou claro para você, mas moderador algum tirou seus votos. Nós **não** temos poder para alterar pontuação.

Porém, o sistema do Stack Overflow identifica **automaticamente** certos padrões de votos, por exemplo, no caso de você ter votado muitas vezes em apenas um usuário.

Muitas usuários fazem isso inocentemente, seja por conhecerem alguém pessoalmente ou, quem sabe, por estarem muito agradecidos depois de terem perguntas respondidas por daquele usuário.

Se alguém abrir várias perguntas ou respostas de qualquer usuário e começar a votar contra ou a favor, o sistema vai considerar isso como um tipo de esquema de votos tendenciosos e toma duas atitudes:

- Os votos geralmente são **automaticamente estornados** durante a noite
- Os moderadores são notificados do fato

Isso não significa que o usuário é considerado um criminoso. É com na porta giratória do banco. Às vezes você é barrado e precisa voltar para deixar o guarda-chuva ou as suas chaves, por exemplo.

Quando os moderadores analisam o caso, eles podem decidir notificar o usuário via e-mail para explicar o que aconteceu.

Em outras situações, os moderadores podem repassar o caso para a equipe de desenvolvedores do SO que então poderá ou não tomar uma atitude.